# What is the size limit of an Array in JavaSCript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to fill an array but when I fill it more than a certain size it stops working.

Is there any size limit on arrays in JavaScript? Is it specified anywhere?

I'm interested in a general answer, but I've spotted it not working using chrome on Windows.

Comment: What do you *think* the limit is? Can you reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle?

Comment: How absolutely humongous are the arrays you're working with? Or is the problem maybe in some other piece of code?

Comment: the maximum length of an array according to the ECMA-262 5th Edition specification is bound by an unsigned 32-bit integer due to the ToUint32 abstract operation, so the longest possible array could have 232-1 = 4,294,967,295 = 4.29 billion elements. Are you using more than that ?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum length of an array is 4,294,967,295 - that is, the maximum unsigned 32-bit integer.

Testing in the browser console yields this result:

[image: Screenshot: Array of size 4,294,967,295 works, but +1 length fails]

If you're making arrays that big... you have problems. Problems like this guy from [Computer Stupidities](http://www.rinkworks.com/stupid/cs_programming.shtml)

> At my previous job, we were porting a UNIX system to Windows NT using Microsoft VC++. A colleague of mine, that was in the process of porting his portion of the code, came to me, looking really upset.
>
> - **Colleague:** "Hey! I hate these Microsoft guys! What a rotten compiler! It only accepts 16,384 local variables in a function!

Comment: Citation required. Also - is that a theoretical or practical limit? (As in - can you _actually_ create an array this big?)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Testing in a browser console yields [this result](http://prntscr.com/66p930)

Comment: Nice, you might want to edit that in.